# Match Substring that contains separators in full string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match

I wasn't sure how to phrase the question. Long story short, I want to pull both strings (`a`, `b`) from the line `In: a (b)`. In almost all cases `a=b`, but just in case, I've separated them. The problem: both strings can contain any character which includes Unicode, white space, punctuation, and parenthesis.

```
1: In: ThisName (ThisName) is in this list
2: In: OtherName (With These) (OtherName (With These)) is in this list
3: In: Really Annoying (Because) Separators (Really Annoying (Because) Separators) is in this list
```

Line 1, easy: `^\w+:\s(?'a'.+?)\s\((?'b'.+)\)` `a:ThisName` `b:ThisName`

Line 2, same as before:`a:OtherName` `b: With These) (OtherName (With These)`

Line 2, lazy: `^\w+:\s(?'a'.+?)\s\((?'b'.+?)\)` `a:OtherName` `b:With These`

Line 3, *head desk*

Is this possible? Perhaps I need to go another route? We know one set of parenthesis is required to be there. Perhaps I have to go down a math route, calculate the number of parenthesis and find that route to determine which should actually contain `b`? Count every open and close somehow.

What I've been playing with: https://regex101.com/r/8YIweJ/2

By the way, if I could change the input formatting, I most definitely would.

Added Question: If that is not possible, does assuming `a=b` all the time make this any easier? I can't think of how it would.

Comment: You can't match parentheses with a non-recursive regex, and Java's regexes are not recursive. Do your lines always have "is in this list" after the "significant" parenthesis?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to get all the different strings separated within parenthesis?   i,e, A string with tokens a(b)c(d(e))f is supposed to return a,b,c,d,e,f, where each {x: [a,f]} can consist of one or more words?

Comment: @RealSkeptic "In:" and "is in this list" will always be there and printed precisely in that fashion.

Comment: And do you have any guarantees that the parentheses (if they exist) in the values of A and B are always matched? That is, that you couldn't get something like `Foo ( Bar`, or `Great :-)`?

Comment: @Amal I would like `a` and `b` in the line `In: a (b) is in this list` For example `In: A (Has These) (B is different but (Has These Too))` would result in `a:A (Has These)` and `b:B is different but (Has These Too)` And to make it more complex, `a` and `b` can contain any character and can be the same, so this can happen: `In: A!@ (☢!) (A!@ (☢!))` or `In: A!@ (☢!) (Other Entirely)`

Comment: @RealSkeptic I just noticed that problem below. If there is a rogue `(` I don't think this is possible and a flag would have to be thrown for that rare scenario. If something like that were to happen, with additional code, it could be detected and marked for human review or something along those lines. If detected it could just clump together a (b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comments are embedded in the `processInput` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "1: In: ThisName (ThisName) is in this list\n" +
        "2: In: OtherName (With These) (OtherName (With These)) is in this list\n" +
        "3: In: Really Annoying (Because) Separators (Really Annoying (Because) Separators) is in this list\n" +
        "4: In: Not the Same (NotTheSame) is in this list\n" +
        "5: In: A = (B) (A = (B)) is in this list\n" +
        "6: In: A != (B) (A != B) is in this list\n";

    for (String line : input.split("\n"))
    {
        processInput(line);
    }
}


public static void processInput(String line)
{
    // Parse the relevant part from the input.
    Matcher inputPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+): In: (.*) is in this list").matcher(line);
    if (!inputPattern.matches())
    {
        System.out.println(line + " is not valid input");
        return;
    }
    String inputNum = inputPattern.group(1);
    String aAndB = inputPattern.group(2);

    // Check if a = b.
    Matcher aEqualsBPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*) \\(\\1\\)").matcher(aAndB);
    if (aEqualsBPattern.matches())
    {
        System.out.println("Input " + inputNum + ":");
        System.out.println("a = b = " + aEqualsBPattern.group(1));
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    // Check if a and b have no parentheses.
    Matcher noParenthesesPattern = Pattern.compile("([^()]*) \\(([^()]*)\\)").matcher(aAndB);
    if (noParenthesesPattern.matches())
    {
        System.out.println("Input " + inputNum + ":");
        System.out.println("a = " + noParenthesesPattern.group(1));
        System.out.println("b = " + noParenthesesPattern.group(2));
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    // a and b have one or more parentheses in them.
    // All you can do now is guess what a and b are.

    // There is at least one " (" in the string.
    String[] split = aAndB.split(" \\(");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Possible Input " + inputNum + ":");
        System.out.println("possible a = " + mergeParts(split, 0, i));
        System.out.println("possible b = " + mergeParts(split, i + 1, split.length - 1));
        System.out.println();
    }
}


private static String mergeParts(String[] aAndBParts, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(getPart(aAndBParts, startIndex));
    for (int j = startIndex + 1; j <= endIndex; j++)
    {
        s.append(" (");
        s.append(getPart(aAndBParts, j));
    }
    return s.toString();
}


private static String getPart(String[] aAndBParts, int j)
{
    if (j != aAndBParts.length - 1)
    {
        return aAndBParts[j];
    }
    return aAndBParts[j].substring(0, aAndBParts[j].length() - 1);
}
```

Executing the above code outputs:

```
Input 1:
a = b = ThisName

Input 2:
a = b = OtherName (With These)

Input 3:
a = b = Really Annoying (Because) Separators

Input 4:
a = Not the Same
b = NotTheSame

Input 5:
a = b = A = (B)

Possible Input 6:
possible a = A !=
possible b = B) (A != B

Possible Input 6:
possible a = A != (B)
possible b = A != B
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into this! The last portion of the method, attempting to guess where the parenthesis are/should be is pretty intuitive too. There are several items in here I wouldn't have thought of trying. Ultimately, I've opted to send along the whole string (`a + b`) in the case parenthesis can't be deciphered and marked it with invalid. I'll be tacking on a small handful of additional variables to full further on down each line and create a class to handle it, I believe. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is not use regular expressions for this. Follow this kind of algorithm:

1. Find the first index of ( that should give you your "a" string if I follow your question
2. From that index go through the string character by character using charAt. Count up when you hit a ( and down when you get to a ). Once you hit zero in this counter then your brackets match and you have the position of the end of your "b" string.

It also looks like there could be multiple string making up "B" (from line 3), so you can just keep iterating over the string per step 2 above, adding the strings to either a list or a string builder as appropriate.

Comment: That algorithm will not solve the problem. The "b" string doesn't start on the *first* left parenthesis. It starts at the parenthesis that matches the last right parenthesis. And as I understand it, there is no guarantee that the parentheses inside the expression are matched.

Comment: True. The only parenthesis that you can guarantee to be matched are the ones containing `b`. Even I hadn't thought that a rogue "(" could be in either one of them. Now that you have enlightened me, I'm really beginning to doubt this is possible. Or, at the very least, make a rule that rogue parenthesis can't exist. i.e. if they happen which could be determined with some additions to his suggestion, make a flag for that match and figure out how to handle it separately. Most likely just combining a and b entirely for those rare situations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could parse your text, but not with a regular expression, and with at least one of the following conditions being true:

1. The parentheses in the B expression are guaranteed to be matched properly. That is, no `)) ((`, `:-)`, etc.
2. The A and B are exactly the same. In such a case, even if you have unmatched parentheses inside them, e.g. `Hello (-: (Hello (-:)`, you know that the `(` before the second `Hello` is the "right" one.

If you can't make those guarantees, then you should write an `isMatchedParenthesis(String)` method, that checks if all parentheses are properly matched. Have a counter, starting from zero, and scan through the string.

- For each character in the string:

  - If current char is `(`, `counter++`.
  - If current char is `)`, `counter--`.
  - If counter is negative, return false
- If at the end the counter is positive, return false. Otherwise true.

Test your string with that method. If it works, you can rely on finding the "significant" parenthesis using parenthesis matching. If it returns false, you can try the fallback method that assumes that both strings are the same.

**Find the significant parenthesis when balanced**

- Find the index of the rightmost `)` (use `lastIndexOf`).
- `counter=0`.
- For each character going down from that index to 4 (The character after `In:`:

  - If it is a `)`, `counter++`
  - If it is a `(`, `counter--`.
  - If `counter==0` stop, return current index.

Now you have the index of the significant parenthesis. Your A is the substring between 4 and this index - 1 (remember the space before the `(`). Your B is from that index+1 to the index of the right `)` that you found first.

**Fallback method**

Suppose your parentheses are not balanced. Can you do anything?

- Make a list of all the indexes of `(` in the string.
- If the length of the list is even - bad string, report to user.
- If the length is odd, take the index of the middle `(`. Assuming that A and B are the same, they should each have the same number of `(`, so the one that has the same number of `(` to its left and to its right is your candidate.
- Extract the A and B as before. If they are not equal - bad string, report to user.

Comment: Thank you very much for plain-jane breaking down the rules. It helps me try to piece the mess back together.